# How to fetch values from object containing array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections

I have an object which looks as below. It can have any number of `Array object` each representing count of `ErrorType`.

```
data = 
{
  "1": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
      "Error": "Wrong Password for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
      "Error": "Host not matching"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
      "Error": "Wrong User for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
      "Error": "connectivity issue"
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
      "Error": "Wrong version"
    }
  ],
  "16": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-4A",
      "Error": "Unknown"
    }
  ]
  ...
  ... 
}
```

I want to capture all the count values and push them in an array `countArray` in descending order.

```
countArray = [16, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1];
```

I want to capture the corresponding `ErrorType` and push them in an array `errorTypeArray`.

```
errorTypeArray = ['Error-4A', 'Error-3A', 'Error-2B', 'Error-2A', 'Error-1B', 'Error-1A'];
```

I have written the following code so far but it is not complete:

```
const countArray = [];
const count = Object.keys(data).length;
for ( let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    countArray.push(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to match the key to the ErrorType, then this will work:

```js
const data = { "1": [ { "ErrorType": "Error-1A", "Error": "Wrong Password for 1A" }, { "ErrorType": "Error-1B", "Error": "Host not matching" } ], "2": [ { "ErrorType": "Error-2A", "Error": "Wrong User for 1A" }, { "ErrorType": "Error-2B", "Error": "connectivity issue" } ], "3": [ { "ErrorType": "Error-3A", "Error": "Wrong version" } ], "16": [ { "ErrorType": "Error-4A", "Error": "Unknown" } ] };

let errorArray = [];
const countArray = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => { // run over the keys
    data[key].forEach(item => {
      errorArray.push(item.ErrorType); // save the errortype
      acc.push(key); // save the key as many times as there are items in the array
    });
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .sort((a, b) => b - a);
errorArray.reverse()
console.log(countArray)
console.log(errorArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it into pairs which contain identical length keys and error values, then sort on integer values of keys.

Once you have this pairwise structure, you can use an array rotation pattern with `map` and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to split it into the desired result.

```js
const data = {"1": [{"ErrorType": "Error-1A","Error": "Wrong Password for 1A"},{"ErrorType": "Error-1B","Error": "Host not matching"}],"2": [{"ErrorType": "Error-2A","Error": "Wrong User for 1A"},{"ErrorType": "Error-2B","Error": "connectivity issue"}],"3": [{"ErrorType": "Error-3A","Error": "Wrong version"}],"16": [{"ErrorType": "Error-4A","Error": "Unknown"}]};

const errs = Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => 
    [v.map(() => +k), v.map(e => e.ErrorType).reverse()]
  )
  .sort((a, b) => b[0][0] - a[0][0])
;
const [counts, errorTypes] = (errs[0] || [])
  .map((_, i) => errs.flatMap((_, j) => errs[j][i]))
;
console.log(counts, errorTypes);
```

Comment: Heh, late night here, so you might be right that there may be a simpler solution but I'm not seeing anything obvious right now...

Comment: So I believe I [fixed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64520799/295783)

Comment: @ggorlen The above code is throwing 2 errors:

 - `TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`
   
   `TS2339: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'any[][]'.`

Comment: I assumed your data wasn't going to have empty arrays based on the provided structure (and no mention of TS). Adding `(errs[0] || [])` should fix the `unknown` issue. `flatMap` might not be available in your version of TS, but you can replace it with `map(...).flat()`, and if that's also not available, there's always `[].concat(...map(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy one is : sort the key and loop over to extract data from it.

```js
const data = {
  "1": [{
      "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
      "Error": "Wrong Password for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
      "Error": "Host not matching"
    }
  ],
  "2": [{
      "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
      "Error": "Wrong User for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
      "Error": "connectivity issue"
    }
  ],
  "3": [{
    "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
    "Error": "Wrong version"
  }],
  "16": [{
    "ErrorType": "Error-4A",
    "Error": "Unknown"
  }]
}

const error = []
const ct = []
// Sort the key
// Loop over and extract data
// Now loop over the data
Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => b - a).forEach(key => {
  const t = data[key]
  for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    ct.push(key)
    error.push(t[i].ErrorType)
  }
})
console.log(error, ct)
```

Comment: This is not what OP wanted. Look again

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of object with count and error type using `for...of`, then sort the array by count like the following way:

```js
var data = 
{
  "1": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
      "Error": "Wrong Password for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
      "Error": "Host not matching"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
      "Error": "Wrong User for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
      "Error": "connectivity issue"
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
      "Error": "Wrong version"
    }
  ],
  "16": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-4A",
      "Error": "Unknown"
    }
  ]
}
var countAndErrorTypeArray = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
   for ( let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj.Count = key;
      obj.ErrorType = value[i].ErrorType
      countAndErrorTypeArray.push(obj);
   }
}
countAndErrorTypeArray.sort((a,b) => b.Count - a.Count);
console.log(countAndErrorTypeArray);

//you can still have the count and error type from the resulted array seperately
var countArray = countAndErrorTypeArray.map(i => +i.Count);
console.log(countArray);

var errorTypeArray = countAndErrorTypeArray.map(i => i.ErrorType);
console.log(errorTypeArray);
```